# Session not saving in ios flutter webview app

Tags: ios, flutter, session, cookies, save

I have some issue with storing session details in my ios app. I created a webview app. Whenever i close the app after logging in, it logs me out and asks for credentials everytime. This is working fine for my android app. Any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the session by calling below code:-

```
 onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
        if (url == null) {
          return;
        }
        final cookieManager = CookieManager.instance();
        final expiresDate = DateTime.now()
            .add(const Duration(hours: 24))
            .millisecondsSinceEpoch;

        List<Cookie> cookieList = await cookieManager.getCookies(url: url);
        cookieList.where((cookie) => cookie.expiresDate == null).forEach(
              (cookie) => cookieManager.setCookie(
                url: url,
                name: cookie.name,
                value: cookie.value,
                path: cookie.path ?? '/',
                domain: cookie.domain,
                expiresDate: expiresDate,
                isSecure: cookie.isSecure,
                isHttpOnly: cookie.isHttpOnly,
                sameSite: cookie.sameSite,
              ),
            );
      }
```

You have to store session or cookies for web view using **CookieManager** and you can call this code when your url is loading is completed.